# What minimum .jars do I need for BlazeDS and Spring?

Tags: java, apache-flex, spring, blazeds

I've managed to create a small project in Eclipse using the Spring & BlazeDS integration. Everything is working fine, my AMF requests are coming through and all is well.

I just want to know what the minimum required .jar's would be. At the moment I have a list of more than 35 jars required to make just a very basic application work.

It just feels like I had to include so much, to do so little. Are there collective libraries that I could include instead of these long lists of .jars?

The list is as follows:

> ```
>   |__antlr-3.0.1.jar
>   |__aopalliance.jar
>   |__aspectjrt.jar
>   |__aspectjweaver.jar
>   |__backport-util-concurrent.jar
>   |__cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar
>   |__commons-codec-1.3.jar
>   |__commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar
>   |__commons-logging.jar
>   |__concurrent.jar
>   |__flex-messaging-common.jar
>   |__flex-messaging-core.jar
>   |__flex-messaging-opt.jar
>   |__flex-messaging-proxy.jar
>   |__flex-messaging-remoting.jar
>   |__h2.jar
>   |__jackson-core-asl-0.9.9-6.jar
>   |__org.springframework.aop-3.0.0.M3.jar
>   |__org.springframework.asm-3.0.0.M3.jar
>   |__org.springframework.aspects-3.0.0.M3.jar
>   |__org.springframework.beans-3.0.0.M3.jar
>   |__org.springframework.context.support-3.0.0.M3.jar
>   |__org.springframework.context-3.0.0.M3.jar
>   |__org.springframework.core-3.0.0.M3.jar
>   |__org.springframework.expression-3.0.0.M3.jar
>   |__org.springframework.flex-1.0.0.RC1.jar
>   |__org.springframework.jdbc-3.0.0.M3.jar
>   |__org.springframework.jms-3.0.0.M3.jar
>   |__org.springframework.transaction-3.0.0.M3.jar
>   |__org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.0.M3.jar
>   |__org.springframework.web-3.0.0.M3.jar
>   |__spring-security-acl-2.0.4.jar
>   |__spring-security-catalina-2.0.4.jar
>   |__spring-security-core-2.0.4.jar
>   |__spring-security-core-tiger-2.0.4.jar
>   |__spring-security-taglibs-2.0.4.jar
>   |__xalan.jar
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't tell for sure, but we can give you suggests:

- antlr can probably go. Spring bundles its own copy in its own JARs
- aopalliance - same reason
- aspectj - are you using aspectJ from Spring? If not, ditch it.
- backport - might be ok to get rid of it, try and see
- cglib - some appservers already have this, so you might be able to get rid of it from the app
- commons-codec - probably not needed
- commons-httpclient - shouldn't necessary
- commons-logging - already included in most appservers, shouldn't be needed
- concurrent.jar - this is an old version of the java5 concurrent API, get rid of it.
- h2.jar - no idea what this is
- jackson - this is a JSON library. If you don't use JSON, you don't need this
- org.springframework.aop - dump it unless you're using AOP
- org.springframework.aspects - dump it unless you're using AOP
- org.springframework.jdbc - dump it unless you're using JDBC
- org.springframework.jms - dump it unless you're using JMS
- org.springframework.transaction - dump it unless you're using transactions
- spring-security - are you using this stuff?
- xalan - you should almost certainly dump this, the app server probably already has copy

All of these suggestions come with a health warning.